# OpenLayers Integration with Angular Accessing Map from Separate Component

Tags: angular, openlayers

How do I access an OpenLayers map object from a separate component? I'm just trying to think more Angularly about this by adding a layer to the map in a separate component rather than all embedded in the map definition.

I have a StackBlitz example prepped: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-openlayers-map-nofzbb?file=src/app/map-interactions/map-interactions.component.ts

The goal here is just to console.log the map object. Once that works, adding the layer should be straightforward.

Comment: First idea: implement a service containing your map and inject this service wherever needed, e.g. into your components.

Comment: @pzaenger - Ahh I was wondering if that's how you would do that. Every example I've seen has the map in the Component. I'm still wrapping my mind around injectables. :-) Thanks for your quick response!

Comment: Maybe [my repository](https://github.com/pzaenger/angular-openlayers) here might help you. It's a simple Angular app with an OpenLayers map. Though, it's a bit old, it should do the trick.

Comment: @pzaenger - Oh, yes that does help a lot! Thank you for sharing!